# The Unique Padlock PIN List!

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

### Introduction

In a private chat, a friend of mine apparently recently stumbled across a security system which has the following two restrictions on its valid pins:

- Each digit must be unique (that is "1" may only appear once)
- The order of the digits doesn't matter ("1234"="4321")

So to illustrate how bad this padlock system is, let's actually enumerate all valid PINs!

### Input

Your input will consist of a single, positive integer, which denotes the length of the PIN.

### Output

Your output consists of a list of non-negative integers or strings*, which enumerate all valid PINs of the given length.

<sub>*More precisely something that a human can use to try all combinations if you would print it for them. This means set of sets of digits and arrays of arrays of digits are fine.</sub>

### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins! Standard rules and [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/55329) apply.

### Corner Cases

- The output behaviour is undefined if an integer greater than 10 is input.
- The ordering of the digits within each output entry is undefined, as entries with a zero actually contain said zero, that is you may not strip "0123" to "123" but "1230", "1203" and "1023" are all valid as is "0123".

### Test Cases

```
1
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

2
[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,32,42,52,62,72,82,92,43,53,63,73,83,93,54,64,74,84,94,65,75,85,95,76,86,96,87,97,98]

3
[210,310,410,510,610,710,810,910,320,420,520,620,720,820,920,430,530,630,730,830,930,540,640,740,840,940,650,750,850,950,760,860,960,870,970,980,321,421,521,621,721,821,921,431,531,631,731,831,931,541,641,741,841,941,651,751,851,951,761,861,961,871,971,981,432,532,632,732,832,932,542,642,742,842,942,652,752,852,952,762,862,962,872,972,982,543,643,743,843,943,653,753,853,953,763,863,963,873,973,983,654,754,854,954,764,864,964,874,974,984,765,865,965,875,975,985,876,976,986,987]

4
[3210,4210,5210,6210,7210,8210,9210,4310,5310,6310,7310,8310,9310,5410,6410,7410,8410,9410,6510,7510,8510,9510,7610,8610,9610,8710,9710,9810,4320,5320,6320,7320,8320,9320,5420,6420,7420,8420,9420,6520,7520,8520,9520,7620,8620,9620,8720,9720,9820,5430,6430,7430,8430,9430,6530,7530,8530,9530,7630,8630,9630,8730,9730,9830,6540,7540,8540,9540,7640,8640,9640,8740,9740,9840,7650,8650,9650,8750,9750,9850,8760,9760,9860,9870,4321,5321,6321,7321,8321,9321,5421,6421,7421,8421,9421,6521,7521,8521,9521,7621,8621,9621,8721,9721,9821,5431,6431,7431,8431,9431,6531,7531,8531,9531,7631,8631,9631,8731,9731,9831,6541,7541,8541,9541,7641,8641,9641,8741,9741,9841,7651,8651,9651,8751,9751,9851,8761,9761,9861,9871,5432,6432,7432,8432,9432,6532,7532,8532,9532,7632,8632,9632,8732,9732,9832,6542,7542,8542,9542,7642,8642,9642,8742,9742,9842,7652,8652,9652,8752,9752,9852,8762,9762,9862,9872,6543,7543,8543,9543,7643,8643,9643,8743,9743,9843,7653,8653,9653,8753,9753,9853,8763,9763,9863,9873,7654,8654,9654,8754,9754,9854,8764,9764,9864,9874,8765,9765,9865,9875,9876]
```

Comment: The input is non-negative - so on input zero, the program should be a list containing one value, the empty string?

Comment: @aschepler indeed, the zero case is about as sensical as the 11 case, so I changed that to "positive integer".

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ØDœc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDJejk5P/H26P/P/fGAA)

## Explanation

```
ØDœc  Double-builtin; main link
  œc  Number of combinations of          of length
ØD                              [digits]
                                                   <right argument>
```

Behavior for `n > 10` is empty list.

Comment: how does it not work with input greater than 10 (tried it, and seemed weird to me)?

Comment: @gnu-nobody it gives the empty list because you can't have a combination of 11 elements with 10 choices.

Comment: oh, the ØD is the "0123456789". thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 89 bytes

Returns a list of lists of digits (as characters), or an empty list if **n > 10**.

```javascript
n=>[...2**29+'4'].reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[x,...y])],[[]]).filter(a=>a.length==n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BbsJADETv@QrfvCap1SIuKGx@JOzBChsaFLwo2SIQ4tvTXeipF3vG46c5yVXmbhou8UPDwS@9XdQ2LTOvV6v1tsQNOp784afzxkh1o3coVR58lou5p8st27sjV7Wtc8T9MEY/GbGN8Oj1GL@tVVqinyNYULAN9EbpxUt2wqcwqEEk@lMVEpSAe8W6KPowmUTBV53gXdqfSZQlwaMA6ILOYfQ8hqPB/IUJVKr/Rbk8dVLxXH4B)

#### How?

We first generate a list of all decimal digits as characters by computing **2<sup>29</sup> = 536870912**, adding the missing **'4'** and splitting:

```javascript
[...2**29+'4'] → [ '5', '3', '6', '8', '7', '0', '9', '1', '2', '4' ]
```

We then compute the powerset:

```javascript
.reduce(                                   ,[[]]) // starting with a[] holding an empty list
        (a,x)=>[                          ]       // for each decimal digit x:
                ...a,                             //   copy all previous entries in a[]
                     ...a.map(y=>        )        //   and duplicate each previous entry y
                                 [x,...y]         //   with x prepended at the beginning
```

Finally, we filter the results on their length:

```javascript
.filter(a=>a.length==n)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
žhæsù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L6Mw8uKD@/8/98YAA)

**Explanation**

```
   sù  # keep elements the length of the input
  æ    # from the powerset
žh     # of 0123456789
```

Comment: Didn't know `ù` was a thing. Pretty sure I've used filter before. How new is that one?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Pretty old. Been there for a long time :P

Comment: Me brain no do see the command before the now. Me brain no am smart.

Comment: Has happened to me a couple of times. More than once on some commands as well, which is...

Comment: ... acceptable of a god-tier 05AB1Er (05AB1E-ite? 05AB1E-an?) such as yourself.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda l:combinations(range(10),l)
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADA3VcwtsZB42biT1xQQZuUlpQuvh7v6uevytrzfnSO5bxj4O3ScpJEJ5UGFuVJsMw4MQ7ZtATyZK7KLVCpaj72aiQOTM0hw4qI/Qc)

Finds all combinations of `0 .. 9` of length `l`.

Behavior for `n > 10` is empty list.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
0~Range~9~Subsets~{#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8d@gLigxLz21zrIuuDSpOLWkuK5auVbtv6Y1V0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDso4Sl1Ksmr5DNReXoQ6XkQ6XsQ6XCRdX7X8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:{d+s for d in`5**19`*n for s in f(n-1)if d>s}or{''}
```

Returns a set of strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc@qOkW7WCEtv0ghRSEzL8FUS8vQMkErDyxSDBRRSNPI0zXUzExTSLErrs0vqlZXr/0PkswDSRYl5qWnahjqKJhqWnFxFhRl5pUo5MEYxflFJakpGkADNDWhYv8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/),  17 bytes

```r
combn(0:9,scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pzk/NylPw8DKUqc4OTFPQ1Pzv9F/AA)

Errors for input greater than `10`.

Returns a `matrix` where each column is a PIN.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
.cUT
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.cUT&input=4&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
.cUT
  UT     [0, 1, ..., 9].
.c  Q    All (implicit input)-element subsets.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->n{[*[*0..9].combination(n)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOlorWstAT88yVi85PzcpMy@xJDM/TyNPM7b2f4FCWrRR7H8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
4Y2wXN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yTSqDzC7/9/IwA)

Returns nothing (empty array) for `k>10`.

```
          % implicit input k
4Y2       % push '0':'9'
   w      % swap top two elements of stack
    XN    % nchoosek, select all k-combinations of '0':'9' as a char array
          % implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>56</s> 50 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [Hat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/hat-wizard).

```hs
(10!)
_!0=[[]]
w!n=[0..w-1]>>=(map.(:)<*>(!(n-1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoQgEADQ/04xwn7MBIr2GY0XMVkk1jYykQq6/c6@903X/ilFMs@Czirq3spyCDF2j6ocrDGPdtF7xiM1gyNNvUeFVTsikiNtFRjaudUbXpBhkN@SS1ov0Utrfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 105 bytes

```java
n->{var s="";for(int i=1024,j;i-->0;s+=" ")for(j=10;n.bitCount(i)==n&j-->0;)s+=(1<<j&i)>0?j:"";return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc4xa8MwEAXgPb/i8BCkNhZO6BTZ7lAodOiUsXRQHNucap@MdDKE4N/uKmmn43gfj2fNbHJ7@VlxnJxnsOlXkXFQXaSG0ZF60ptmMCHAp0GC2wZgiucBGwhsOJ3Z4QXGlIkTe6T@6xuM74NMNFmA9/@i8oO47Vu/@2M1dNVKeX2bjYdQZZnunBdIDFjti8PLzmrM87rQ4bnKIJP31KZEkzojv7lILFBWFW3tg8nkxL4s7RZlXbzaY2r0LUdPEPSy6seW0zVwOyoXWU1pBA8kOmWmabiKg5R3s2yW9Rc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

```hs
f 0=[[]]
f n=[a:x|x<-f$n-1,a<-[0..9],all(/=a)x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwDY6OjaWK00hzzY60aqipsJGN00lT9dQJ9FGN9pAT88yVicxJ0dD3zZRsyL2f25iZp5tQVFmXomKQpqC0X8A)

### Explanation

When the number of digits is zero there is only one combination, that is the empty one:

```hs
f 0=[[]]
```

When the number of digits is `n` and `n/=0` the combinations are all the ways to add digits to combinations from `f$n-1` such that no digit is addded to a combination that already contains it.

```hs
f n=[a:x|x<-f$n-1,a<-[0..9],all(/=a)x]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia),  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

```
₸…K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3@FR045HDcu8//83AgA)

It's been a while since I posted an answer in Gaia! *Thanks to Mr. Xcoder for saving a byte!*

```
      % implicit input n
₸     % push 10
 …    % pop 10, push 0..9
  K   % all subsets of size n
      % print top of stack implicitly
```

Comment: You don't need `@`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks. Didn't realize that; it doesn't seem to be documented very clearly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>51</s> 36 bytes

```
.+
10*
"$+"{%`^.
*_$&
L$v`_+
$.%`$%'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@by9BAi0tJRVupWjUhTo9LK15FjctHpSwhXptLRU81QUVV/f9/YwA) Outputs nothing for `n>10`. Explanation:

```
.+
10*
```

Replace the input with 10 `_`s.

```
"$+"{
```

Repeat the rest of the program `n` times.

```
%`^.
*_$&
```

Prefix each number with `_` repeated according to its first digit.

```
L$v`_+
```

Match all `_`s, but include all of the following `_`s in the match too, for which we need to enable overlapping matches.

```
$.%`$%'
```

For each `_` found, prefix the number of `_`s to its left to the number.

This is a bit tricky so perhaps an actual case would be better. Let's suppose that we've already run the loop twice, so that all 2-digit PINs have been generated, and we're currently working through them to create 3-digit PINs. We'll look at what happens to `36`: The first digit is `3`, so three `_`s are prefixed, to make `___36`. This then creates the following matches, marked here with `` `' ``s:

```
Match   $%` $.%`
`___'36     0
_`__'36 _   1
__`_'36 __  2
```

`$%'` evalutes to `36` in all three cases, resulting in the 3-digit PINs `036`, `136` and `236`.

If we were then to go on to create 4-digit PINs, then `036` would not have any `_`s prefixed, and therefore would result in no matches at all in the final output.

Comment: The question says the input is non-negative. On input zero, this outputs ten underscore characters.

Comment: @aschepler Indeed; I see the OP has decided to exclude that case, but in case you're wondering, the fix would be to prepend `^0` and `¶` at a cost of 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 43 bytes

```
(0..9)&__import__("itertools").combinations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDAXQu3SQZCmCk4NnCSoWAm1@SXP/@N50BCzblbTXevImomPCQ4SKxucB9FW4vhiP2h0KWzldLajrCmp0MHP@)

Proton finally outgolfs Python :D I thought `(import itertools)` would return the value but apparently I failed at that. Also importing `*` afterwards doesn't work because it's not in a lambda, it's a top-level expression.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 5 bytes

Outputs an array of digit arrays. Outputs *all* combinations if input is `0` or an empty array if input is `<0` or `>10`.

```
Ao àU
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QW8g4FU=&input=OAotUQ==)

---

### Explanation

```
          :Implicit input of integer U
A         :10
 o        :Range [0,10)
   àU     :Combinations of length U
```

Comment: I don't think the output for input 0 is correct. The output should be a list containing one element, which is empty.

Comment: @aschepler, where are you getting that from?

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
Vd,S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JrPj/PyxFJ/h/7n8jAA)

`Vd` is `"0123456789"`.  `,` pushes the input to the main stack. `S` gets combinations of the specified size.

In the tio link, `m` is used in the footer to print each output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>124</s> <s>122</s> 121 bytes

```ml
open List;fun f(s:: &)m=(if exists(fn x=>x=m)s then[]else[m::s])@f&m|f&m= &
fun!0=[[]]| !n=concat(tabulate(10,f(!(n-1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc2xTsQwDAbgvU/xt0PlSHfoTmxBQaxIbIyhoHBK7iolTtX4oEPfvYRj5Zfswf5klxT3KUrmbcuTZ7yMRR7ClRGoaI1eJUNjgF/qvFBgLOZxMUkVyMWzHXws3iaty6CeQp/WWgZ9Uy@0B2PtMKxo2Zwyn5yQuM9rdOLpeNgFaon3R1Wz/f4rl/wNywNqDJ5Z7iS/yjzyGYx3dG/cNcD654i1ntW/btfVfkNz03y5iI/KkptAU0WCfFsqUIt7tf0A) Example usage: `!2` yields `[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[0,7],[0,8],[0,9],[1,0],[1,2],[1,3], ...]`.

**Ungolfed:**

```ml
open List;

(* int list list -> int -> int list list *)
fun f (s::r) m =
    if exists (fn x => x=m) s 
    then f r m
    else (m::s) :: f r m
  | f [] m = []

(* int -> int list list *)
fun g 0 = [[]]
  | g n = concat(tabulate(10, f(g(n-1))))
```

---

**Some alternatives:**

#### <s>125</s> 123 bytes

```ml
fun f(s:: &)m=(if List.exists(fn x=>x=m)s then[]else[m::s])@f&m|f&m= &
fun!m 0=[[]]| !10n=[]| !m n=f(!0(n-1))m@ !(m+1)n;!0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xa8MwEIV3/4onD0ZHmmDTTUEla6BbR1UJGazG4DsHS2k9@L@7crLmwT0e3Hf3Ivdb7tMgyxLugqCjMaiIre4CPruYdu2UPeogmOzHZJki0rUV59s@to6NiZ4OoeI5j0VV5DeKUVvnvJ@hmlqsWwNDbNCq1rJtiPgApXnTkOxVvV9@Lz0ULLq03iNehz848ciyOErapeErjZ38QHBC@S1lAcxPTosxI73k3srsD2gsirXjnDG@3KBvGUoYHkuCVnin5R8) Defines an anonymous function which is bound to `it`.

#### <s>127</s> 124 bytes

```ml
fun!0=[[]]| !n=let fun f(s:: &)m=(if List.exists(fn x=>x=m)s then[]else[m::s])@f&m|f&9=[]|f&m=f(!(n-1))(m+1)in f(!(n-1))0end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BTsMwEETv@YpJDtGuoFUrTlgy4orEjaMxqBJ2G8m7qWIDOeTfg1s4MocZafZpJ0vaSCqjrmv81HZnnfN@Qas2hYJaIVI2Bj2LpSHiechlG@bqmaJitg@zFc4op6DOh5SDE2Oy58fYyxL7e@t8DbGRWtLNnpnkZs/D5e9fsQv6cRlHPo3fcOpRZfGkZVvGlzINeoTiDd2rdg2w/HKkxkz8L3fbVb9CU9N8HRLeKyaHM@hcoYLxemRQiztefwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
f=(i,b='',k=10)=>k--?f(i-1,k+b,k)+f(i,b,k):i?'':b+`,`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcrBDkAgAIDhuxepVlnhlMWrVMhSk2FeP7rq9u/bv@lHX9PpjpvucV5SshI6YiQAxEvOkBw8paOFjnLisSEeYZuHL4QbARAGq0qlvprifsWw1CGu0EKG0J94SU1JbUldpvQC)

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle 18 SQL, 169 bytes

Not a golfing language but:

```
WITH t(v)AS(SELECT*FROM SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)),n(a,b,c)AS(SELECT a,-1,''FROM i UNION ALL SELECT a-1,v,v||c FROM n,t WHERE v>b)SELECT c FROM n WHERE a=0
```

Expected the input to be in a table `i` with column `a`:

```
CREATE TABLE i (a INT);
INSERT INTO i VALUES ( 3 );
```

Try it online at [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com) (a free login is required then copy-paste the solution into a worksheet) or [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73b74/2) (no login but requires +7 bytes to work on the lower Oracle version).

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
{Ae!f<:$_|}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9oxVTHNxkolvqb2v1WEdWFdRMF/EwA)

Technically doesn't run on tio.run, since heap space runs out. However, it works properly for up to 9 digit keypads, and should run just fine with more RAM.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Dennis

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>113</s> 99 bytes

```bash
p()(r $1 0 $[10-$1])
r()for i in `seq $2 $3`;{ (($1>1))&&r $[$1-1] $[i+1] $[$3+1] $4$i||echo $4$i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgFAX3PcVbfILSCvkxO6EXCYGkjSVuNNXuas9uo6t58Jh5rGkv5RBSRBCjB03cK@JZXqKQrxDh4DyWZN@gAaQX84UQxHeWsutOaSJWPJ901wbSjSO5nO1zD22aX6ktX1uMARqjwRZwgDwyjjV9LFTabgbVqZ@35Q8)

Comment: `r 0` doesn't work.

Comment: `r` is the recursive function: it's not meant to be launched with only 1 parameter. `p 0` behaviour is unspecified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 67 bytes

```
n=>n?[for(x of f(n-1))for(y of Array(x?+x[0]:10).keys())y+x]:['']
```

Port of my Retina answer, but works for `n=0` too (returning a list of an empty string, as distinct from an empty list for `n>10`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
⊞υωＦχ≔⁺υＥυ⁺κＩιυΦυ⁼θＬι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gtDhDo1RHoVzTmistv0hBw9BAU8GxuDgzPU8jIKe0GCTnm1gAosDcbB0F58TiEo1MTSDQUSgFagsoyswr0XDLzClJLQKpcy0sTcwp1ijUUfBJzUsvyYCotf7/P9o49r9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υω
```

Push the empty string to the predefined list.

```
Ｆχ
```

Loop over each digit.

```
Ｅυ⁺κＩι
```

Append the digit to every string in the list.

```
≔⁺υ...υ
```

Append the result to the original list.

```
Φυ⁼θＬι
```

Print all strings with the correct number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 20 bytes

```perl6
{combinations 10,$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@786OT83KTMvsSQzP69YwdBARyW@9r81V3EiSFrDUBPONEIwjRFMS03r/wA)

This is exactly what `combinations` (as a subroutine, or `.combinations` on a list) is for.

https://docs.perl6.org/routine/combinations

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

.. frustratingly longer than [Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166735/80062) and [R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166737/80062) `f=:{[:(#@>"0]/.])[:<@I.@#:@i.2^]`
[TIO](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WqjraSkPZwU7JIFZfL1Yz2srGwVPPQdnKIVPPKC72f2pyRr6Cekl5vkJaUX6uQnFmhbq1gpFCmoIZF1jKQsHQVEXBGChgaPAfAA)